# Operator replacement "with" in strict mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have string value which entered user, for example the variable f.

```
f = "1/log(x)";
```

In vanilla JavaScript, i used operator with:

```
f = "with (Math) {" + f + "}";
```

The code work excellent in vanilla javascript, but i use Vue js and have problems in strict mode. I don't know how replace this operator. Who faced with this problem please answer me.

I try this:

```
            let math = Math
            math.f = f
            console.log(f)
```

But nothing working.

Comment: Other than defining all the methods yourself or detecting all the math items you use and replacing it, there is nothing you can do since with is not supported in strict mode.

Comment: shortly, my easily way is a change vue js on jquery for example?

Comment: Not sure how jQuery can be used as a replacement for vue.

Comment: The fact is that in jquery this code is working, with operator "with".

Comment: because you are not using strict mode with jQuery. If you set strict mode it will also fail.

Comment: You can also use a library like https://mathjs.org/

Comment: is true, but this need me for only not strict mode. I show this app only once

Comment: hm, this library mb, will help

Comment: Which problems with strict mode do you have exactly? And what are you doing with `f`? The code you've shown just creates a string, no problems with that - do you `eval` it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically with is not recommended to be used because it can cause issues in programs. So what are your options?

define a bunch of globals

```js
const sqrt = Math.sqrt
const log = Math.log

const test1 = new Function("a","return sqrt(a)")
const test2 = new Function("b","return log(b)")

console.log(test1(4))
console.log(test2(100))
```

Other option is to do the replacements with a reg exp

```js
const fixMath = eq => eq.replace(/(sqrt|log|pow)/g,'Math.$1')

const test1 = new Function("a", fixMath("return sqrt(a)"))
const test2 = new Function("b", fixMath("return log(b)"))
const test3 = new Function("a", "b", fixMath("return pow(a, b)"))
const test4 = new Function("a", "b", fixMath("return sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2))"))

console.log(test1(4))
console.log(test2(100))
console.log(test3(10, 3))
console.log(test4(3, 3))
```

Comment: Log is a for example. The math function entered user.

Comment: so.... how is it any different than the string that is hard coded? You would need to set all the properties of Math you want to support,..